# Dynamic calculations while mySQL database updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of items that are each individually associated with a category by means of an integer in a row called *category*. I also have a display order for each item, relevant to its associated category. This is saved in a row called *pictureorder*. Straightforward?

My problem arrises when the user deletes a category that contains items/pictures that are associated with it. I tell mySQL to search for any items associated with the category and to associate them with a 'default' category which is denoted by 0.

```
// IF THERE'S ANY PICTURES THAT WERE IN THAT CATEGORY,
// MOVE THEM INTO THE DEFAULT CATEGORY.
$uncategorise = "UPDATE pictures 
    SET category = '0'
    WHERE category = '$categoryID'
    AND username = '$userID'";
$queryUncat = mysql_query($uncategorise) or die(mysql_error());
```

This works. However, the items' pictureorder is broken as items transferred from the deleted category may create duplicate pictureorders in the default category. I'm aware of how to solve this problem in a manner which would make multiple calls to the database. This feels too expensive. My query is whether I can use some technique I'm unaware of to update an incrementing pictureorder integer to the database as it's called without making that row a key? Something along the lines of:

```
$uncategorise = "UPDATE pictures 
    SET category = '0',
        pictureorder = 'TotalofDefaultCategory++'
    WHERE category = '$categoryID'
    AND username = '$useID'";
$queryUncat = mysql_query($uncategorise) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advance!

### Update1

Based on Kyle's suggestion below, I am trying the following without success:

```
UPDATE pictures 
    SET category = '0',
        pictureorder = (SELECT COUNT(category) + 1 WHERE category='0' AND username='$useID')
    WHERE category = '$categoryID'
    AND username = '$useID';
```

If I omit `pictureorder = (SELECT COUNT(category) + 1 WHERE category='0' AND username='$useID')`, the category does indeed get changed to '0' whenever the category matches `$categoryID` and `$useID`. However, if I include the addtional line, nothing changes. I don't get any errors but pictureorder doesn't change. Nor does category. Is the syntax correct?

Also, if I replace `pictureorder = (SELECT...` with `pictureorder = 2` it works as expected. So I can't see a possible problem other than the syntax being incorrect (I hope it's not, as I feared, that it was too good to be true that you could include a `COUNT` in this manner).

Comment: Is the pictureorder of the records in category zero important ? if not set them to NULL

Comment: It is in so far as the backend puts the Default category through the same functions as other categories. It would involve a lot of work to alter every function that deals with pictureorders just to exclude the Default one.

However, it is an interesting suggestion so if the only solution for this involves a lot of database calls, it may be worth pursuing. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been scratching my head for two days solid on this one as it turns out none of the solutions were quite right. Marc B led me on the right path although I couldn't add to a user-defined variable in a second query in PHP, though I was able to call on it (hence some misguided trials and errors). There is a way of querying MySQL in PHP that can make multiple queries and connect them but the `mysql_query` method I was already using was too deeply interwoven in my site to make it an easy change.

Instead, based on the fact that the category to be deleted ($categoryID) had existing pictureorders starting from 1 and incrementing. I was able to use this existing information to add onto the COUNT suggestion made on this page. So, although I had to use two queries, for the second one I simply added the existing pictureorder of the deleted category onto the total count of the default category for the current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server-side var:

1st query:

```
select @cnt := 1;
```

2nd query:

```
update pictures SET pictureorder := @cnt, @cnt := @cnt + 1
WHERE ...
order by pictureorder, ...
```

You'll need an appropriate `order by` clause to ensure that the records with duplicate pictureorder values get put in the right order - do the moved records come before or after the records that were already in the category?

Comment: This method is a little bit new to me so please excuse my lack of full commentary on it until I research it more thoroughly and get my head around it. The moved records come after the existing default records, therefore there's no work involved in altering the existing default records pictureorder. Thanks!

Comment: You can even do it in a single query: `UPDATE pictures AS p INNER JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 1) AS sq SET ...`

Comment: Thanks Mchl, I'm a little lost on that one and amn't familiar enough with mysql to get what you abbreviated.

Comment: Also, I must mention that the original suggestion doesn't appear to address that the category must also be changed (as well as the pictureorder).

Comment: Hmmm... `@cnt := @cnt + 1` is not working. It's claiming to be incorrect SQL syntax (both through PHP and as a query in a console)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get a sum of the default category for that particular user?  If you aren't trying to do it by user, remove the `AND username='$useID'` from the portion I added to your query

```
UPDATE pictures 
    SET category = '0',
        pictureorder = (SELECT COUNT(category) + 1 WHERE category='0' AND username='$useID')
    WHERE category = '$categoryID'
    AND username = '$useID';
```

Comment: Just for that particular user. Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: Try this query?  Does it produce the results you want?  It should get a count of the records where category is 0 (your default) for that particular username.

Comment: I almost missed your count suggestion. I was thinking it was referencing a PHP variable. Is it too good to be true that it will return a total for the 0 category while it is querying the database?

Comment: What it does is count how many rows are returned that have a value of 0 for that username.  It should do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: the count going to fail if you remove a picture in the midle of the list, i should have replaced "COUNT(category) + 1" whit "MAX(pictureorder) + 1"

Comment: Is this syntax correct? `pictureorder =  (SELECT MAX(pictureorder) + 1 WHERE category='0' AND username='$useID')` ? It's causing trouble.

Comment: Why are you using MAX pictureorder?  I thought you wanted a count where the category='0'.  If you want a count where the category='0', then that is what I gave you.  Maybe I'm just not understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because the comment following yours suggested to. It read to me as though he was advising this as an improvement on COUNT of category0. My less informed mind sees the COUNT of category0 and the MAX of pictureorder as having the same result (in theory). I've switched back to COUNT category0 and am getting the same problem of no changes occuring in the update once I include (SELECT COUNT...

Comment: Just confirmed the syntax in this answer is wrong for SQL (if anyone googles this).

Answer (score 0):

if category 0 have orders in the range 1-150, and category 5 that going to be deleted have a range from 1-7, you should be able to just add 150 to the current value, and by that get the numbers 151-157

```
UPDATE pictures 
SET category = '0',
    pictureorder = pictureorder + '$default_max_pictureorder'
WHERE category = '$categoryID'
AND username = '$userID'"
```

Comment: true, but the chanse of 2 people whit the administartion rights to remove categories, removing a category at the same time, is quite low, and to protect against that you can lock the table

Comment: The setup of this site involves every user having their own frontend and backend access to things such as categories so the chances are increased. Thanks for the suggestion!